# Github shows 4% of repository is in a language that is not used in repository

Tags: github, github-linguist

I have a personal repository on GitHub that is completely written in C#, with a few XML configuration files, and some PowerShell files from included NuGet packages.  On the main repository page, GitHub shows a colored bar to display the breakdown of different languages used in the repository.
[image]

If you click this bar, it shows the language names and actual percents.
[image]

This particular language breakdown seems a bit odd to me, since I am the only contributor, and I have never used Smalltalk.

If you click a language name, it will show you a list of the files using that language.
[image]

In this last image, you can see on the left side that the repository really only contains C#, XML, PowerShell, text and markdown files.

So why does GitHub think I'm using Smalltalk?  And why doesn't the color bar mention that I'm using XML?

Comment: You should ask this question to GitHub support, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since GitHub is using [**linguist**](https://github.com/github/linguist) to detect languages, you can open a PR to report some files incorrectly tagged as "Smalltalk".

For instance, [issue 2012](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2012) is still active (even though it is closed).

Comment: Wow, that's dead on.  4% of C# misidentified as Smalltalk.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As Philip and VonC noted, GitHub uses [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) to compute the language statistics.

**So why does GitHub think I'm using Smalltalk?**

Linguist relies first on the file extension to determine the language of a file. It then uses a set of [refinement strategies](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/edabdc75a5373e84dccc059a48cfc2d7c38bbde1/lib/linguist.rb#L49-L67) for conflicting extensions (e.g., `.cs` is used by both Smalltalk and C#). These refinement strategies are not 100% accurate (in can even get pretty bad for small files). Thus, files with conflicting extensions may be classified incorrectly.

**How can I fix it?**

You can use [Linguist overrides](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides) to tell Linguist that all `.cs` files in your repository are C# with a `gitattributes` file:

```
*.cs linguist-language=C#
```

**And why doesn't the color bar mention that I'm using XML?**

Linguist only counts *programming* and *markup* languages in the statistics. XML is classified as [a *data* language](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/edabdc75a5373e84dccc059a48cfc2d7c38bbde1/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L4843).

**Why doesn't Smalltalk appear in the search results?**

The search results are cached to avoid computing them every time you visit the page. They probably weren't up-to-date when you took the screenshot.

Comment: Those old linguist questions do need your expertise! +1

Comment: Looks like you did a pretty good job answering all of them ^^
We could use your help at [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues).

Answer (score 1):

GitHub uses a heuristic to identify the language(s) of your repository.  The underlying library is [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist).  Misclassification is common enough that it's the top Troubleshooting section: [My repository is detected as the wrong language](https://github.com/github/linguist#troubleshooting).